# Breaking of spherical symmetry in crystals

Tags: angular-momentum, solid-state-physics, symmetry-breaking, crystals

I have been reading the book [Transition Metal Compounds](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/transition-metal-compounds/037907D3274F602D84CFECA02A493395), and when the author begins to discuss transition metals in crystals, they state

> When we put a transition metal ion in a crystal, the systematics of
>   the corresponding electron states changes. For isolated atoms or ions
>   we have spherical symmetry, and the corresponding states are
>   characterized by the principal quantum number $n$, by orbital moment $l$
>   and, with spin–orbit coupling included, by the total angular momentum
>   $J$ . When the atom or ion is in a crystal, the spherical symmetry is
>   violated; the resulting symmetry is the local (point) symmetry
>   determined by the structure of the crystal. Thus, if a transition
>   metal ion is surrounded by a regular octahedron of anions such as O2, the d levels which were fivefold
>   degenerate in the isolated ion ($l$ = 2; $l_z$ = 2, 1, 0, −1, −2) are
>   split into a lower triplet, $t_{2g}$ , and an upper doublet, $e_g$.

My question is the following: if spherical symmetry is broken, why should we expect any of the previous quantum numbers to make any sense? I would have expected that breaking this symmetry would have done much more than just break the fivefold degeneracy within the $l=2$ subspace - rather, the resulting states of definite energy could be combinations of any number of states with different angular momentum ($d$ orbitals, $s$ orbitals, etc.). Is this something unique to the specific crystal structure they consider?

Comment: The levels that do not get mixed up perhaps are localised to the atom when compared to the lattice constant. In this sense for those levels there is some semblance of spherical symmetry.